# AD integration with Windows using Ansible

Tags: active-directory, window, ansible

Is there any module to integrate Active Directory with windows using Ansible ? I am executing some Powershell command to add my windows instance in Active Directory ? Can any one suggest me how we can do via ansible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `script` command to execute powershell scripts. See module here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html

`tasks:
    - script: foo.ps1 --argument --other-argument`